# Connect android 5.0.2 phone to Fedora 21 with Android Studio and adb

Tags: android, linux

I have been developing with Android Studio and an LG G2 phone connected to my Fedora 21 desktop.  Everything was working great and I could test on my LG g2 via usb connection.  After the phone decided to upgrade itself to 5.0.2, Android Studio and adb stopped seeing the phone.  I spent all morning mucking with udev rules to no avail.  My fedora desktop sees the phone just fine with lsusb and the phone is mounted via mtp and I can access the phone's filesystem.  For some reason though, adb does not list it as a device after the android upgrade.

Any suggestions?  udev rules from github match the phone and set its permissions properly.

lsusb output:
  `Bus 002 Device 024: ID 1004:633e LG Electronics, Inc.`

I'm using the udev rules from 
    `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules/master/51-android.rules`

ls -l /dev/android_adb 
    `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr 23 11:18 /dev/android_adb -> bus/usb/002/024`

udev rules:
  `ATTR{idVendor}!="1004", GOTO="not_LG"
   ENV{adb_user}="yes"
   ATTR{idProduct}=="633e", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
   ENV{adb_user}=="yes", MODE="0666", GROUP="users", TAG+="uaccess"`

Oh yeah, I should add.  When phone is plugged into USB, it shows the "USB debugging connected" icon in the top title bar.  Thus, I'm wondering if this is a bug in adb and AndroidStudio.

Thanks,

Bobby

Comment: An upgrade can conceivably change the VID/PID, so Include your udev rule and your lsusb listing of the phone in your post.  You did restart/reload udev, right?  You might also want to disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone, and clear host authorizations.  Finally, if your VID is not one widely known as an Android one, you may have to add it to a ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

Comment: Yes, I tried reloading/re-starting udev.  I reloaded the rules and explicitly restarted the service.  I re-started AndroidStudio.

Comment: lsusb outputs: Bus 002 Device 023: ID 1004:633e LG Electronics, Inc.

Comment: Again, include this and the udev file entry in the body of your post.

Comment: I just checked the adb sources, and it has known to look for LG's 0x1004 VID for a while now, so the adb_usb.ini listing is probably not the solution.

Comment: Hey, how does one add to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini?  I don't know the format of the datafile.  I don't have the tool "android" on my system to update the file for me.  Thanks.

Comment: There are a number of questions here and references elsewhere on that.  But it doesn't seem to be your issue.

Comment: I've submitted a ticket via code.google.com.  If I resolve this issue, I'll post answer here.

Answer (score 0):

After an enormous amount of searching, testing, experimenting, and with the help of the google android folks, I found a solution.

Under settings -> tethering & networks -> usb tethering

I enabled usb tethering and adb can now correctly see my phone and I can download code to it for debugging and testing.

Thanks,

Bobby